# Can conditional operator be used to toggle between two class member function calls

Tags: c++11, conditional-statements, pointer-to-member

Consider this:

```
int func1( int i );
int func2( int i );
```

Conditional operator can be used like that:

```
int res = (cond)?func1(4):func2(4);
```

Or, if both may use the same parameter:

```
int res = ((cond)?func1:func2)(4);
```

Now, what about member functions of a class:

```
class T
{
public:
    T( int i ) : i(i) {}

    int memfunc1() { return 1*i; }
    int memfunc2() { return 2*i; }

private:
    int i;
};
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
T t(4);
int res2 = t.((cond)?memfunc1:memfunc2)();
```

...tried other syntax too (`(t.*((cond)?&(T::memfunc1):&(T::memfunc2)))()`) with no success...

Is that doable and then what would be the good syntax? One line code answer are preferable (using a temporary auto variable to store pointer to function would be too easy...;-)

Comment: `(t.*( cond ? &T::memfunc1 : &T::memfunc2))()`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: It works, I can't believe you only had to remove parenthesis from my try....;-)! Please post as answer to get deserved reputation.

Comment: What's wrong with the good old `cond ? memfunc1() : memfunc2()` ?

Comment: @n.m.: Nothing wrong, except when it takes many parameters...if they are the same, it's better to avoid copying/pasting them for the two statements.

Comment: @jpo38 Another possibility would be to use a tag or enum to do the dispatch so that you don't need to resort to this horrible syntax. Something like `auto tag = cond ? memfunc1 : memfunc2; memfunc(tag, arg1, argn);`. Or maybe just `memfunc(cond, arg1, argn);` if the semantics are right.

Comment: If it takes enough parameters for this to be a problem, that's too many parameters.

Comment: better use bind: `int res = std::bind((cond ? &T::memfunc1 : &T::memfunc2),t)(args...);`, at least it is easier to understand. But I strongly recommend to use simple syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

§ 5.3.1 [[expr.unary.op]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#4)/p4:

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a [*qualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#qualified-id) not enclosed
>   in parentheses. [ *Note:* that is, the expression `&(qualified-id)`, where the [*qualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#qualified-id) is enclosed in
>   parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member.” Neither does [*qualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#qualified-id), because
>   there is no implicit conversion from a [*qualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#qualified-id) for a non-static member function to the type “pointer to
>   member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to the type “pointer to function” [(4.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.func). Nor is
>   `&unqualified-id` a pointer to member, even within the scope of the [*unqualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#unqualified-id)’s class. — *end note* ]

If it still doesn't help, you can uncover the correct syntax below:

> `(t.*(cond ? &T::memfunc1 : &T::memfunc2))()`